# How to remove the last row objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I remove an last records from object

```
var a = this.data();
console.log(a);
```

before remove

```
1) Object { type="marker",  categories=[1],  coords=[2],  more...}  
2) Object { type="marker",  categories=[1],  coords=[2],  more...}
3) Object { type="marker",  coords=[2],  ident="place",  more...}
```

i want remove number 3 or 2 or 1

after remove

```
1) Object { type="marker",  categories=[1],  coords=[2],  more...}  
2) Object { type="marker",  categories=[1],  coords=[2],  more...}

BB.gmap.marker.prototype.display = function() {
    var a = this.data();
    a.splice(-1);
    console.log(a)
    if ("object" != typeof a.coords)
        return this.error("Requires coordinates [lat, lng] at BB.gmap.marker.display()"),
        !1;
    var b = {
        map: this.controller().map(),
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(a.coords[0],a.coords[1]),//27.6648274 -81.51575350000002
        optimized: !1
    };
}
```

Comment: What is your exact structure? 1), 2), 3) is not a structure...

Comment: And btw, basically objects are not ordered, so you can't really say "last"

Comment: Provide the exact output of `console.log`.

Comment: amir design  can you please provide the exact output of `console.log(a);`.Just copy from console and paste in your question by editing it. Don't do any edite in the copied data, paste as it is

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have array of objects like: `[{},{},{}]`.

So need to do like below:-

```
a.splice(-1);
```

Example:-

```js
var a = [{type: "marker",categories: [1],coords: [2]}, {type: "marker", categories: [1],coords: [2],}, {type: "marker", categories: [1],coords: [2]}]; // i think you have array of object

a.splice(-1);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Objects don't have the `splice` method. It's an array method.

Comment: try this but show error  a.splice is not a function

Comment: This answer is not relevant because you don't know what is the type of the variable from the question.

Comment: @amirdesign  please show the exact output of `console.log(a)`.don't add number from your side

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not asked the question correctly. What i understand from your question is that you have an array of Objects and you want the last object to be removed from it. For this, you can do:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{type="marker",  categories=[1],  coords=[2],  more...},
                       {type="marker",  categories=[1],  coords=[2],  more...}];

arrayOfObjects.splice(-1);
```

Comment: @amirdesign  instead of saying `"not worked"` .show us the exact output of `console.log(a)`.please don't do any modification in that output while pasting that (as you did in your question)

Comment: TypeError: a.splice is not a function
a.splice(-1);

Comment: This means `a` is not an array. Please check what exactly you need and edit your question accordingly. You can try considering `typeof a` and then show it in your question.